# Cannot deploy Cloud Run application after switching to Secret Manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I have an application that I had previously used environment variables for things like keys. I'm trying to switch to Secret Manager as it's more secure, and did these steps:

- Went through each secret I'd like to migrate
- Added the same secret name & value to Secret Manager
- Created a new revision in Cloud Run
- Added each secret and gave the app permission to access each one, each secret was mounted as an environment variable so the application should function normally.
- Deployed

After attempting this, Cloud Run attempts to launch the new revision for several minutes until finally giving this error:

[image]

So I waited a couple hours and tried again to no avail.

### Here's my problem:

- Why did this happen? I cannot think of a reason why the container would fail to deploy in this situation.
- Where can I find logs? I would try to diagnose the problem but I don't know where to look. There's no logs beyond the failure message in Cloud Run logs, and nothing on the Secret Manager side either.

The code for the application has not changed, and I double checked that all environment variables are named correctly and exist. If the application itself were failing I would normally see logs in Cloud Run but logs for this event at all seem to be missing entirely. Any help or insight would be appreciated!

Comment: This error occurs during container import. Edit your question and include the commands you are using. Try using [gcloud builds submit](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit) and report the error. My guess is that you have an illegal character (non-UTF8) somewhere perhaps in one of the environment variables.

Comment: I'm not using any command-line tools. This is being done from the cloud console.

Comment: I eventually got it working, but still have no idea why it was broken. I just made a small change and pushed it and it worked. ‍♂️

Comment: For problems like this, I always recommend using the command line so that you can see the steps and error messages.

Comment: @JohnHanley that sounds like sound advice. I’ll do that in the future!